# Does differential equation always has solution if vector field is only continuous?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $V$ be a $continuous$ vector-field defined on a domain $U$ in $R^n$
. Let $x_0$
be a point in $U$. Is it true that the differential equation $\frac{dx}{dt}$ = $V(x)$ admits
a solution $\phi(t)$ satisfying initial condition $\phi(0)$=$x_0$    defined on some open
interval containing $0$.

By Arnold's Book Existence theorem I know that unique solution exists in case of smooth vector field.But here vector field is only $continuous$.Can we have counterexample in this case?

Comment: Funny. This was asked yesterday too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.It is called [Peano's existence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_existence_theorem).

Comment: does Peano's existence extend to higher dimensions?

Comment: Yes. However, you loose uniqueness (in all dimensions).

Comment: Oh i see..i wonder why in arnold's book smooth vector fields are only considered

Comment: I guess it is because in most physical applications you want uniqueness of solution.